# Get Azure app service Principal using MSAL library java

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-ad-msal

How to get Azure Service principal id for App registered in Azure and to verify roles added to that by using MSAL Library Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate service principal

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client,
               tenant,
                key,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

Azure.Authenticated azureAuthClient = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials);
String clusterId = "xxxxxxx";
ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal =
                azureAuthClient.servicePrincipals()
                        .define(clusterId)
                        .withNewApplication("http://easycreate.azure.com/" + clusterId)
                        .definePasswordCredential("sppass")
                        .withPasswordValue("StrongPass!12")
                        .attach()
                        .create();
```