# app 1 calls app 2 so which SP credentials should we provide

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-service-principal

i want to clear 1 confusion.
we have an application which can be called by multiple apps.

So in order to accomplish service to service authentication, which Service principal should I use during authentication using java MSAL libraries?

should the Service principal credentials belong to the "caller application" or the "callee application"?

I see that in all samples, SP is hardcoded in property files, this shows that they belong to "callee application" but in that case do we share the SP with all the calling application?

And how about if we want to restrict few applications

Comment: For the application which is called by multiple apps, it should [validate the roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=aspnetcore#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps). For the applications which require to call that app, using client credential flow to generate access token. I don't know how to write code, but the flows are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   **`You can surely restrict the few applications with the proper use of service principals (Application registrations in Azure AD) by assigning them roles according to the required level of access since the concerned SP’s credentials are managed by Azure AD itself and their API access can be managed by the permissions given to them regarding specific Azure resources such as Microsoft Graph, Azure Blob storage, etc`**.

Also, the **service principal created will be a managed identity either system-assigned or a user-assigned accordingly wherein the client ID, the value of the secret generated, tenant ID and the display name will only be used by the Java MSAL libraries for Azure AD authentication purposes**.

•   An example of it is given below: -

To create a service principal and configure its access to Azure resources, kindly refer to the below command for the configuring the same: -

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac -n <your application name> --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID
```

Check the returned credentials and note down the following information regarding the Azure AD service principal created: -

```
AZURE\_CLIENT\_ID for the appId 
AZURE\_CLIENT\_SECRET for the password
AZURE\_TENANT\_ID for the tenant
```

Once done, then you can use them as shown below in your Java webapp deployed: -

```
 /**
 *  Authenticate with client secret.
 */
 ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new 
 ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
 .clientId("<your client ID>")
 .clientSecret("<your client secret>")
 .tenantId("<your tenant ID>")
 .build();

 // Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter.
 SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
 .vaultUrl("https://<your Key Vault name>.vault.azure.net")
 .credential(clientSecretCredential)
 .buildClient();
```

•   As shown above, you can surely use the service principal created using RBAC in Azure AD app registration in Java webapp deployed in Azure. Please find the below snapshots of the same: -

[image: Azure AD App registration]
[image: Azure AD identity assignment]

Please find the below links for more information on this : -

***[Get Azure app service Principal using MSAL library java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508292/get-azure-app-service-principal-using-msal-library-java)***

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth***